# A Prison Officer's Password

Tags: story, anagram, music

Prison is not a nice place to be. *Especially* when you've been wrongly convicted.

The Officers have sympathized with you, however, and one in particular, a very musical chap, has become good friends with you.

But then today, the Governor - a horrid man who hates prisoners, and also the man who wrongly convicted every single prisoner in the prison - burst in and ordered your officer friend's arrest.

As he was dragged away he shouted this to you:

> Remember my password? Keep a record of it! The Governor will go mad but it will change the lives of you and the other prisoners! Traits run in the family!

And then he was gone.

You remember the time he had told you his password so you could hack his computer and try and look up the Governor. His password is

> **S3 2B3 8C**

## Can you prove you and your jailmates' innocence?

To get you started:

> Your friend didn't like the new cd or earphone methods of listening to music, he preferred using an old record player...

And

> Abbreviations

Comment: @Techidiot ha! haaa

Comment: @lois6b You never know :)

Comment: _Especially_ may be related to KYLIE MINOGUE's _Especially For You_ where something is mentioned about _time_ saying **all the time** Since I am bad with decrypting, someone can try it out.

Comment: @Techidiot you are on the right lines with music but the password is the important part here, and the text will help

Comment: Even the lyrics has a line saying _You changed my life... ooh_ Not sure if that is relevant here. @BeastlyGerbil I am no good with drilling through the hidden text. Involves lot of brains :(

Comment: @Techidiot if it helps then I've deleted the steganography tag because its not relevant

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil- It definitely helps :) Is the answer one word or a complete sentence/explanation to how to get out of jail ? :-/ You can chose not to answer if you want

Comment: @Techidiot you can deduce how from your friends last words but you have to solve the password first

Comment: I'm going to assume `S3` is a member of the family with 3 sisters. `2B3` 2 brothers, 1 dead (was 3 brothers)? `8C` 8 children.

So someone in the family that fit these criteria?

Comment: @jordsta95 completely wrong track

Comment: Wasn't there a French boy band called 2B3? Also, I'm thinking that record players had different speeds: 33 1/3, 45 and 78. A handwritten 8C could look like 78 when turned upside down, and S3 and B3 look a little like 33.

Comment: @paolo way to complicated - see the latest tag

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Is the latest tag related to latest update? Or is applicable to all the text :D You can decline to answer if you want

Comment: @Techidiot just the password

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I'm wondering if there's a wall involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes the final answer -

> If the numbers in password are ommitted, we get **SBC** whose anagram is **CBS** abbreviation of which is [Columbia Broadcasting System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBS) which can be linked to music. May be he is asking to keep recordings of whatever the Governer speaks or may be he had previous recordings of Governer which all jailmates may use to prove their innocense.
>
>
>  Friend said *to keep a record of it* Which says its one of the recordings of CBS. Now if the numbers are reversed, we get [8323](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankrobber) Which is a song with Wiki Label **CBS 8323** and offcourse a recording of CBS. The [lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tt4qykoy7odypu26hx3fbwjw5zq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) of the song say *My daddy was a bank robber*. Friend said *Traits run in the family* So someone out there from the Governer's family still do the crimes of robbing.
>  
>
>
>  So, all jailmates need to come together and blackmail the Governer with this fact and in return should ask him to confess his crimes and leave them all.

Comment: Close! You got the letters the wrong way round though. Try an arangement linked to music...

Comment: Lol. Not an american so didn't searched for any anagrams for music with the 3 letters. "Columbia Broadcasting System" is what I can get for now.

Comment: you got the first part - now the letters. Think about a keeping a 'record'

Comment: May be a recorded tape which is proving their innocense. May be he recorded some voices from the Governer in the tape using the old method - "walkman" may be.

Comment: have you noticed CBS is SBC backwards? Maybe you should try adding the numbers in reverse too....

Comment: CBS 8323 is something called "Bankrobber" by The Clash.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan YES!

Comment: And I got 106 by adding them. Which can be an emergency number or 8323 can be related to some address

Comment: I think it's more likely we're supposed to understand that the Governor is a bank robber, or to find something enlightening in the lyrics of that song, or something.

Comment: And it seems _"Original sound recording of Bankrobber is made by CBS Records" _

Comment: The song says 'my daddy was a bank robber' and your friend says 'traits run in the family' when talking about the governor

Comment: It also says _There is a hole in the wall_ which may lead them to any of Governer's relative

Comment: Or may be blackmail him? and ask him to confess?

Comment: You might want to add about the keep a 'record' clue

Comment: In a non-ideal world, the Governor would then plan the bombing of the jail and then blame miscreants for trying to frighten the public...